# I want to concatenate two values into a single string

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two different values systolic and diastolic blood pressure readings in string. When those two values come from front-end I'll store them into a single string, e.g., if systolic ='120' and diastolic='80' I want `bp='120/80'`

```rb
module Api
  module V1
    module CheckinMachine
      class BpsController < ApplicationController
        include MachineError
        before_action :authenticate_user!

        def create
          raise BatteryNotFunctionalError if battery_functional?
          # user = User.find_by!(bp_machine_imei: params[:imei])
          health_reading = current.health_readings.create!(key: :blood_pressure, value: bp_value)
          Solera::PostActivityApi.call(user,
                                       bp,
                                       health_reading.solera_activities.new)
          head :ok
        rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound => _e
          render_machine_error and return
        end

        def show
          puts params
        end

        private

        def bp
          {
            systolic_blood_pressure: params[:systolic],
            diastolic_blood_pressure: params[:diastolic]
          }
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

That's what i have tried, what do i do to make it exactly like i want it to be

like bp = '120/80'

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have the 2 values stored in params, this is super easy:

```
bp = " #{params[:systolic] / #{params[:diastolic]} "
> bp = " 120/80 "
```

Remember that Ruby has the variable substitution in strings using the `#{x}` syntax where `x` is a variable value.

So for instance:

```
x = "apples"
y = 5

string = "I have #{y} units of #{x} to sell you"
puts(string)

> "I have 5 units of apples to sell you"
```